# How to pass anonymous struct as function argument

Tags: go, struct, anonymous

The problem is that I can't access struct properties inside `Converter` function, but I can print em.

```golang
func main() {

    var io struct {
        Src   string
        Dest  string
    }

    flag.StringVar(&io.Src, "src", "temp_dir", "")
    flag.StringVar(&io.Dest, "dest", "users_dir", "")

    modules.Converter(&io)

}
```

```golang
// ./src/modules/converter.go
package modules

func Converter(io interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(io)
    // => {temp_dir users_dir}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
What is the right way to pass multiple props into function?

Comment: Use a named struct type, not an anonymous one. And use this named type for the parameter of `Converter()`.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to change the io struct to Io

```
var Io struct {
       Src   string
       Dest  string
   }
```

And the function input should change this way

```
package modules

import "fmt"

func Converter(io *namePackage.Io) {
    fmt.Println(io.Src,io.Dest)
}
```